# jQuery not displaying correctly fixed on refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a thumbnail slider on my web page which i am developing. Now when i go into the website it shows only a little block of the picture but once i refresh the page all is good, any ideas why this happens

http://www.ap2x.gbes.co.za/1/1.html
that is the page in question

i have tested on firefox, chrome and IE. Error does not seem to be browser specific

Slider works perfectly fine off line with no such problem.
I have no idea what could be causing this

```
        $(function() {

            //  wrap all thumbs in a <div> for the 3x3 grid
            $div = null;
            $('#thumbs').children().each(function(i) {
                if ( i % 9 == 0) {
                    $div = $( '<div />' );
                    $div.appendTo( '#thumbs' );
                }
                $(this).appendTo( $div );
                $(this).addClass( 'itm'+i );
                $(this).click(function() {
                    $('#images').trigger( 'slideTo', [i, 0, true] );
                });
            });
            $('#thumbs img.itm0').addClass( 'selected' );

            //  the big-image carousel
            $('#images').carouFredSel({
                direction: 'up',
                circular: false,
                infinite: false,
                width: 500,
                height: 281,
                items: 1,
                auto: false,
                scroll: {
                    fx: 'directscroll',
                    onBefore: function() {
                        var pos = $(this).triggerHandler( 'currentPosition' );
                        $('#thumbs img').removeClass( 'selected' );
                        $('#thumbs img.itm'+pos).addClass( 'selected' );

                        var page = Math.floor( pos / 9 );
                        $('#thumbs').trigger( 'slideToPage', page );
                    }
                }
            });

            //  the thumbnail-carousel
            $('#thumbs').carouFredSel({
                direction: 'up',
                circular: false,
                infinite: false,
                width: 550,
                height: 150,
                items: 1,
                align: false,
                auto: false,
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like it doesn't work until the images have been loaded so you either need to tell the slider how big the images will be once they are loaded or wait till they are loaded before running your script.

Does adding the following CSS solve the problem?

```
#images img {
    height: 281px;
    width: 500px;
}
```

I can't get the bug again to test it myself.

Comment: Hey Laurence i do have that in CSS still doesn't solve the problem. i am using firefox but the error occurs on IE and Chrome so its not browser specific thanks for the suggestion though

Answer (score 0):

I bet you're viewing this website with Chrome.
There is a nasty bug with this browser when he cannot determine the height of an element.
A workaround would be setting width and height to each slider image manually through css.

Comment: I am using firefox bud this error doesnt seem to be browser specific hey